# slight jiggle or shake results in laptop's lcd to ripple in one (small) spot

Tags: laptop, lcd, hardware-rec

Even applying a tiny bit of pressure to the frame surrounding the lcd causes it. Is this damaging or a sign of bad assembly?

To be clear: this happens in exactly one place on the LCD, regardless of where I touch.

Comment: If it's within warranty I would contact the technical support of the manufacturer. They should be able to determine if there is a fault, and if necessary provide the repairs.

Comment: They basically said "I don't have a schematic of it so I can't tell you if it's normal but try using another laptop of the same model".